# SharedPreferences data not found

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get SharedPreferences to work but with no luck. I have been checking all of the values going into the save, and everything looks like it's working correctly; however, when I go to retrieve the data that was saved, it's not found. I've tried a few different methods, including getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) to get the preferences. The current method I'm using was the solution to someone else's answer but not mine.

Saving:

```
    Log.i("MineStalker", "Saving");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
    Set<String> server_set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (MinecraftServer server : servers) {
        server_set.add(server.getDataString());
        Log.i("MineStalker", "Save loop");
    }
    Log.i("MineStalker", "Save size: " + server_set.size());
    editor.putStringSet("server_data", server_set);
    editor.commit();
```

Getting:

```
    servers = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> server_set = new HashSet<String>();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    preferences.getStringSet("server_data", server_set);
    Log.i("MineStalker", "Create size: " + server_set.size());
```

Summed up, the data that I'm saving isn't showing up.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to equate the variable when calling getStringSet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the docs ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))), getStringSet returns the data, and the second parameter is a default value to return if no value is found for the key. something like this should work:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Set<String> server_set = preferences.getStringSet("server_data", new HashSet<String>());
    Log.i("MineStalker", "Create size: " + server_set.size());
```

from the docs:
Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.

Comment: Oh that explains a lot. The way the tutorial supplied by Android shows it is a little confusing. Thanks for the help.